# Change all 'disabled' attributes to 'readonly' attributes on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-ajax

I've been using the `disabled` attribute on input text boxes to make them uneditable. The problem is I can't change the font color of a `disabled` field in IE.

So I'm trying to change all the `disabled` fields to `readonly` fields on page load using the following code:

```
$("input[type=text][disabled]").attr("readonly","readonly").removeAttr("disabled");
```

No matter where I put the above code it does not work. But when I run it in the script console it works.

**UPDATE:**
Found the reason. I am using ASP.NET Ajax which provides a `pageLoad` -- in my case the code inside `pageLoad` was disabling my textboxes. Added the above code at the end of 'pageLoad' event and it works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to wrapp it with `.ready()` function?

Comment: *"No matter where I put the above code it does not work"* Where have you tried? Provided it's *below* all of the elements with that attribute in the markup, that should work. (Or use `ready`, but there's no need to use `ready` if you can put the script tag below the other elements in the markup.)

Comment: @Sergio: Yes, I did wrap it inside `ready`.

Comment: I'd recommend `$("input:text[disabled]").prop({readonly:true, disabled:false})`

Comment: Do you have a link with a example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
$(function() { /* your code */ });
```

this will execute the code after the page has been loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You can try that inside the onload event,

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("input[type=text]:disabled").attr("readonly","readonly").removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

Comment: If you have jQuery available, you should use it to bind events!

Comment: …but one of them could be coded better. Also, please explain what the difference is and what option to choose in what situation.